# Javascript accordion menu problem in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

hi
all i am working on wordpress project there is i used accordion for right sidebar but all the link are over lapping each other in IE8 its working fine mozzila so plz help my code is

```
<script>
var parentAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("parentAccordion");
parentAccordion.init("acc","h4",1,-1);

var nestedAccordion=new TINY.accordion.slider("nestedAccordion");
nestedAccordion.init("nested","h4",1,-1,"acc-selected");
</script>

<div class="widget-container widget_categories">
<?php
$args = array('parent'=>0,'hide_empty'=>0);
$cats = get_categories($args);

echo '<ul id="acc" class="acc">';
foreach($cats as $key => $val)
{
    $args1=array(
        'showposts' => 10,
        'category__in' => array($val->term_id),
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $post=get_posts($args1);

    echo '<li><h4>'.$val->name.'</h4>';
    echo '<div class="" style="opacity: 0; height: auto;">';
    echo '<ul id="nested" class="acc">';

    if(isset($post) && !empty($post))
    {
        foreach($post as $key1 => $val1)
        {
            echo '<li class="cat-item"><a title='.$val1->post_title.' href='.$val1->guid.'>'.$val1->post_title.'</a>';
        }
    }

    $subcats = get_categories(array('parent'=>$val->term_id,'hide_empty'=>0));

    if(isset($subcats) && !empty($subcats))
    {

        foreach($subcats as $k => $v)
        {
            echo '<li><h4 class="">'.$v->name.'</h4>';

            $args2=array(
                'showposts' => 10,
                'category__in' => array($v->term_id),
               'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );
            $post1=get_posts($args2);

            if(isset($post1) && !empty($post1))
            {
                echo '<div class="" style="opacity: 1; height: auto;">';
                echo '<ul class="children" style="padding-left:15px;">';
                foreach($post1 as $key2 => $val2)
                {
                    echo '<li><a title='.$val2->post_title.' href='.$val2->guid.'>'.$val2->post_title.'</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul></div>';
            }

        }

    }

    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
</div>
```

so plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you have set your DOCTYPE correctly?
For Tiny accordion to work you need the following doctype, just add it at the top of your file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN” “http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey, maybe I'm just being dumb but shouldn't:

```
echo '<li class="cat-item"><a title='.$val1->post_title.' href='.$val1->guid.'>'.$val1->post_title.'</a>';
```

be

```
echo '<li class="cat-item"><a title='.$val1->post_title.' href='.$val1->guid.'>'.$val1->post_title.'</a></li>';
```

I can see firefox being clever about things, but IE is often a little more strict about closing tags. Hope that helps =]